# How to make the font-size of the caption of a Vaadin Label smaller?

Tags: java, css, font-size, vaadin7, caption

I know how to add styles in Vaadin and I've done multiple stylings in my css and added the style in the code succesfully, but this one eludes me.

I tried the following:

in the css I have the following style:

```
  .v-caption-mystyle .v-captiontext {
    font-size: 13px !important;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: $dark-grey;
  }
```

In the code I try to set it in two following ways and nothing happens:

```
postalCodeLabel= new Label(currentAddress.getPostalCode());
postalCodeLabel.setCaption("Postal code"));
postalCodeLabel.addStyleName("v-caption-mystyle");

postOfficeLabel = new Label(currentAddress.getPostOffice());
postOfficeLabel.addStyleName("v-caption-mystyle");
postOfficeLabel.setCaption("Post office"));
```

**EDIT:** Vikrant Thakur's answer works.
In my case also this worked:

```
  .v-caption-invoiceaddress-label-caption .v-captiontext {
    font-size: 13px !important;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: $dark-grey;
  }
```

And in the Java:

```
postalCodeLabel = new Label(currentAddress.getPostalCode());
postalCodeLabel.setCaption("myCaption"));
postalCodeLabel.addStyleName("invoiceaddress-label-caption");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Here is the code for theme scss file:

```
@import "../valo/valo.scss";

@mixin mytheme {

    // Insert your own theme rules here
    .v-caption-mystyle {
        .v-captiontext {
            font-size: 13px;
            font-weight: bold;
            color: red;
        }
    }

    @include valo;
}
```

And, here is the Java code:

```
Label label = new Label("This is the label text");
label.setCaption("This is the label caption");
label.addStyleName("mystyle");
```

Comment: Don't forget to delete browser history in order to load fresh css.

Comment: It works. The .v-captiontext seemed to be the missing part for me. I'll mark your answer as correct one, and also add to my question description the version that worked for me as well.

Comment: Actually, its the order of rules that matters here. Putting "@include valo" before your custom rules has no effect.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming PLabel is either a typo or a custom implementation of the Label class. If that is the case, it's simply that even though you're setting the caption on the Label class, it's CSS class is v-label. So your CSS should look like this.

```
.v-caption-mystyle {
    font-size: 13px !important;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: $dark-grey;
  }
```

Comment: Made the typo corrections. Thanks, I will try this now.

Comment: Hmm, still no effect.

Comment: Inspect your label in chrome. It will show you where each CSS property is coming from.

Comment: I've updated the css, not referring to v-label should make it work.